# Is it possible to use Java WebSockets in Eclipse without Jetty?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, websocket, jetty

I am trying to develop a web server using Java's WebSockets. I am using Eclipse with Tomcat 7, so the javax.websocket-jar file is already included.

I created a simple ServerEndpoint

```
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/login")
public class LoginServer {
    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message) {
        User foobar = new User("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
        return foobar.toString();
    }
}
```

Then I opened the console in Firefox and tried to connect:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/MyServer/login');
```

This ends in an error message which says it can't connect (404).

So I searched the web and found this Jetty thing. I don't really want to add an unnecessary layer on top of my software, but I couldn't find a way to connect to my server.

Do I need to use Jetty when programming WebSockets in Eclipse? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I wanted to have a minimal example so I wanted to add the methods bit by bit. But I needed the @OnOpen method. Now it works. (Embarrassing...)

Comment: `@OnOpen` is definitely not a requirement.